# Pandas slicing by index inconsistency

Tags: pandas, indexing, slice

I have the following DataFrames/Series exhibiting very surprising `[]` slicing behaviour:

```py
# slicing by integers force iloc-like indexing even if index is integer
In [1]: pd.DataFrame({"a": {3: 1, 1: 2}})["a"][2:]
Out[1]: Series([], Name: a, dtype: int64)

# slicing by index element uses sort order of index,
# and in this case dict insertion order is NOT respected
In [2]: pd.DataFrame({"a": {"d": 1, "b": 2}})["a"]["c":]
Out[2]: 
d    1
Name: a, dtype: int64

# if index is not sorted,
# slicing by index element that is not present
# should trigger an exception
In [3]: pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2]}, index=["d", "b"])["a"]["c":]
Out[3]: 
b    2
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Isn't the last one a bug in Pandas as it is supposed to trigger an Exception?

Moral of the story: never use `[]` on a DataFrame or Series, especially with slices...

Comment: what output did you expect? i don't 100% understand the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're overlooking the differences in two types of selection supported in Pandas:

- Selection by position: works like a regular integer-based indexing. When you select with `iloc` or simply with `Series[:2]` (integer index), this will be used. Read more [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-position).
- Selection by label: if the index is sorted, Pandas will include in the slice anything that is between the start and stop labels, and exclude anything that is not. When you select with `loc` or `Series['c':]` (label index), this will be used. Read more [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#slicing-with-labels).

---

Your first example:

```
pd.DataFrame({"a": {3: 1, 1: 2}})["a"][2:]
```

1. You select using `[2:]`.
2. This will select anything starting at position `2` in a zero-index based array. Nothing is returned, since the index only has 2 elements.

```
Series([], Name: a, dtype: int64)
```

Compare this with selecting from position `1`:

```
pd.DataFrame({"a": {3: 1, 1: 2}})["a"].iloc[1:]
```

```
1    2
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

---

Your second and last examples (they both give the same result to me):

```
pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2]}, index=["d", "b"])["a"]["c":]
```

1. You select a slice beginning at label `'c'`, using `["c":]`.
2. Since `'d'` and `'b'` are ordered in decreasing order, this will select anything beginning at label `'c'` (including) up until the end of the index, which is `'b'`:

```
b    2
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Compare this with an unordered index:

```
pd.DataFrame({"a": [0, 1, 2]}, index=["a", "d", "b"])["a"]["c":]
```

This will raise a `KeyError: 'c'`.

Comment: ah, so the crucial thing I didn't realise is that ["d", "b"] is also considered ordered. thanks for the explanation!

Comment: what version of pandas are you using? I'm using 2.0.3, and the constructor of a Series from dict does not preserve dictionary order, so it reorders both the first and second examples.

Comment: @user1537366 Interesting. I'm using 2.2.1 and it respects dictionary insertion order. I tested on 2.0.3 and indeed it **does not**. In both versions the code documentation says "If data is a dict, column order follows insertion-order". I suppose it was a bug that was fixed at some point between these versions, but I couldn't find anything in the [release notes](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/index.html).